# Can a cell in ui-grid be rendered with a custom template?

Tags: ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Disclaimer: I'm new to UI-Grid

According to the ui-grid documentation, it is possible to style a [cell by providing a class](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/111_cellClass).

But is it possible to choose a template for a given cell? I'd like to do more than style just the class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use **cellTemplate**

This is default cell template

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>'
```

[Here is Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qyVyMDqp8rOxS11MXvfe?p=preview)